# backbonejs remove anomaly concept

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I was building a small app for adding and deleting li from ul using Backbonejs.One of the SO members cymen helped me code it, using that i tailored the code a little.currently if i add one element and delete , it works , but the second time i add an element (to ul) and go to delete it , i get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined

Pasting my code here ,

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<button id="add">Add</button>
<ul id="mylist"></ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

        var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend();

        var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

            el:$('body'),

            tagName:'li',

            initialize : function(e){
                this.collection.bind("add",this.render,this);
                this.collection.bind("remove",this.render,this);
            },

            events:{
                'click #add' : 'addfoo'                
            },

            addfoo : function(){
               var myname= $('#name').val();
               $('#name').val('');               
               this.collection.add({name:myname});
            },

            render : function(){

                $('#mylist').empty();
                this.collection.each(function(model){
                    console.log("myView");
                    var remove = new myRemoveView({model:model});
                    remove.render();
                });
            }
        });

        var myRemoveView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el:$('body'),

        events:{
            'click .button':'removeFoo'
        },

        removeFoo : function(){
            console.log("here");

            this.model.collection.remove(this.model);
        },

        render : function(){
            console.log("second view");
            $('#mylist').append('<li>'+this.model.get('name') + "<button class='button'>"+"delete"+"</button></li>");
            return;
        }


        });
        var view = new myView({collection: new myCollection()});
            });
```

Two things i did not understand :

i) in the removeFoo function , we write

> this.model.collection.remove(this.model)

shouldnt this have been this.collection.model.remove , something of that sort ?

ii) i add a li to ul , then i delete it , when i add another li (appending to ul works perfect) but this time when i go to delete it throws me the above error : Uncaught TypeError :cannot call method 'remove' of undefined

can you please help me figure out these 2 doubts in my code , btw SO member cymen's code works like a charm only my tailored code (above) is giving me errors.

SO member cymen's code  : [JS Fiddle for his code](http://jsfiddle.net/Gd2Rs/)

Thank you

Comment: Why is `myRemoveView` bound to `<body>` rather than `tagName: 'li'` (and no `<li>` wrapper in `render` of course)?

Comment: @muistooshort i read somewhere that , the identifier i specify in events ie 'click <some_identifier>' , backbonejs searches for the identifier in the el tag so i just broadly specified body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `myRemoveView` is using `<body>` as its `el`:

```
var myRemoveView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('body'),
```

That means that every time you hit the delete button, you're going to trigger `removeView` on every single `myRemoveView` you've made. That's certainly not what you want to happen and part of the reason that cymen is using `tagName: 'li'`. There are two general rules for views and their `el`s:

1. One view per `el` and one `el` per view. You don't want views sharing the same `el` because of the event handling problem; doubly so you don't want several instances of the same view sharing an `el`.
2. The view's `el` should be the part of the DOM that the view cares about, no more and no less. This makes cleaning up quite easy, just delete the DOM element associated with your view and most things go away with it (DOM events in particular); for non-DOM events, we have a [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) method on views.

Another thing, your view shouldn't (generally) be messing with the DOM outside it's own `el`. This looks very odd:

```
render : function(){
    $('#mylist').append(...);
    return;
}
```

The caller should be responsible for figuring out where your `el` goes, your view should only concern itself with things happen inside it, some other view should be responsible for `#mylist`. Also, `render` methods conventionally return `this` so that you can do this:

```
$(x).append(some_view.render().el);
```

to put them into the DOM.

Specifying both `tagName` and `el` in a view:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    tagName: 'li',
```

is pointless, the `tagName` will be ignored and `el` will be used.

You're also using Backbone 0.5.3 in your fiddle. You should be using the latest versions whenever possible.

If we correct the above, then everything starts working (again):

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    render: function() {
        $('#mylist').empty();
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            var remove = new myRemoveView({
                model: model
            });
            $('#mylist').append(remove.render().el);
        });
    }
    //...
});
```

and:

```
var myRemoveView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    //...
    render: function() {
        this.$el.text(this.model.get('name'));
        this.$el.append("<button class='button'>delete</button>");
        return this;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2z4SA/1/

---

So what sort of craziness was going on with your original version? The key is `el: $('body')` in your `myRemoveView`. First we'll add a little logging method to `myRemoveView` to make it easier to watch what happens:

```
_log: function(method) {
    console.log(
        method,
        ': model =', this.model.cid,
        ' got-collection =', this.model.collection ? 'yes' : 'no',
        ' view =', this.cid
    );
}
```

Note that `cid` is an internal unique ID that Backbone creates, it is just a convenient way to keep track of things. Then we'll call `this._log` in `removeFoo` and `render`:

```
removeFoo: function() {
    this._log('removeFoo');
    if(this.model.collection)
        this.model.collection.remove(this.model);
},
render: function() {
    this._log('render');
    $('#mylist').append('<li>' + this.model.get('name') + "<button class='button'>" + "delete" + "</button></li>");
    return;
}
```

Here's a simple process that should show you were everything goes wrong:

1. Add **a** to the list.
2. Add **b** to the list.
3. Hit **a**'s delete button.

You can follow along here: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yLYNL/

First we'll add **a** and this pops up in the console:

```
render : model = c1  got-collection = yes  view = view2
```

Then we add **b** and see this:

```
render : model = c1  got-collection = yes  view = view4
render : model = c3  got-collection = yes  view = view5
```

Your `myView` render redraws the whole collection so we see `c1` for **a** and `c3` for the new **b**. So far so good, everything makes sense.

Now, when we'll try to delete **a**; first we see that we `removeFoo` on **a**:

```
removeFoo : model = c1  got-collection = yes  view = view2
```

That will trigger a `myView#render` which redraws the whole collection. The whole collection is just **b** at this point so we see `c3` rendered again and everything still makes sense:

```
render : model = c3  got-collection = yes  view = view6
```

But now we see everything go sideways:

```
removeFoo : model = c1  got-collection = no   view = view4
removeFoo : model = c3  got-collection = yes  view = view5
```

You'll see `c3` show up because you have two `myRemoveView` instances (one for **a** and one for **b**) bound to the same `el` so both of them will see the `click .delete` event, it just so happens that `c1` sees it first.

But what is that `c1` doing there? That's the one that doesn't have a collection, that's the the one that is triggering your original error. You never detach your `myRemoveView`s from events on `<body>` so you have a zombie: even though the `<li>` is gone, the view is still bound to `<body>` through the view's [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) call. So you have a zombie view that references a zombie model, zombies zombies everywhere and you left your zombie fighting kit in the car. But why doesn't `c1` have a collection? Well, you did :

```
this.model.collection.remove(this.model)
```

on `c1` to remove it from the collection; removing a model from a collection removes the model's `collection` because, well, the model is no longer in a collection.

Comment: the effort you have taken , *bows* , i will try all of this in some time and will get back to you if  i have any doubts, thank you so much, really really thank you !

Comment: First of all thank you v v much , @muistooshort , i have a couple of doubts i) you said that both my views should not use el : 'body' , why and how does using tagName : 'li' solve the problem ? ii) I understood that both instance of view were listening for delete button click , but i did not understand the last 2 lines , why doesnt c1 have a collection ? In a nutshell how did using tagName in  myRemoveView solve the problem ?? thank you really helped me understand backbone much better :)

Comment: @user1537158: `tagName` solves the problem because that creates a new `<li>` for the view and attaches the jQuery `delegate` to that `<li>` so that events are localized to just that view; otherwise, you'd have two `delegate`s attached to the same `<body>` (hence apparently doubled events) and, since `<body>` is never removed, you get zombies. `c1` won't have a collection because removing a model from a collection removes the model's `collection` property; you start with two references to `c1` (the view & the collection), the collection removes `collection` when the model is removed.

Comment: you have been v v helpful thank you so much , i have a better understanding of backbonejs , really really thank you @muistooshort